# jQuery animate Background Color slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to animate the background color when hovering an element.

For instance, say I have a div which when I hover, I want the background to change into red, and slideDown, and fadeOut on mouse leave.

```
$('div.Item').hover(function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red').slideDown(400);
},
function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent').fadeOut(400);
});
```

There are 2 issues with this.. the SlideDown isnt working, the color red just comes in.. also on mouse leave, the element is completely dissapearing (I am assuming because the fadeOut is working on the element itself and not the transition for background-color).

Is there any tutorial or anyone that can help achieve this please?

Comment: `.slideDown` is applied on your element , not on background color

Comment: Yes i know, how can I make that on the background color? thats the issue I am having

Comment: SlideDown applied to a background-color??? What do you mean/expect?

Comment: something like this: http://pixelgrade.com/demos/senna/ ..hover the magnifying glass item in the menu, it has the slideDown effect

Comment: were you able to get a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same effect by making it a background image, also using the .animate to change css and animation effects together instead of keep chaining, this code would help:

```
$('#nav a')
.css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} )
.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(0 250px)"}, 
        {duration:500})
    })
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, 
        {duration:500})
    })
```

check this [***LINK***](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations) and see the demo too!

Comment: This is the closest answer, however my problem is that I want a dynamic color, allowing the user to change it rather than having a fixed image.

Comment: @Kelish There's an approach but I don't think it is semantic nor a smart move, you can have another div beneath your div -*which you have to set its background to transparent in this case*- and you animate it when the user hover on the required div, something like this `$('#nav a').mouseover(function(){$(#backDiv).animate({top: '150px'}, 2000)}).mouseout(function(){$(#backDiv).animate({top: '0px'}, 2000)})`

Answer (score 0):

That's because fadeOut is a jQuery Object method. It would only work on DOM elements, selected with jQuery. 
The most elegant solution to your problem would be to use CSS [transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp).

Here is a pseudo css snipet with your requirments:

```
div.Item
{
    background-color: #your-background-color;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
div.Item:hover
{
    background-color: #your-new-background-color; 
}
```

Always try to write as little code as possible. And avoid capital letters in your css class names.

Comment: This will fade the background color, it needs to be an image to be slided like in his example link.